# Split comma sepearted from Variable and check if it contains a specific number in Sql server Stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure in which i declared a variable and getting multiple values in it (separated with comma)

I want to check if it contains a specific number.If contains then run other queries.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Aaaaand the query/solution you've tried so far is. Your problem with the solutions you've tried is... You cannot figure out which specific part of the problem? SO is not a code generation service, please show some effort to encourage us to help you. I would also suggest to read [ask] in [help].

Comment: Sql Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Aaron Bertrand's split string function](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4140/removing-duplicates-from-strings-in-sql-server/) you can do something like this.

```
DECLARE @CSVString NVARCHAR(MAX) = '13,4325,345,987, 432';
DECLARE @Id_To_Find INT = 4325

;WITH cteIdSplit
AS(
        SELECT
            CAST([Value] AS INT) 'Id'
        FROM
            dbo.FN_SplitString_AB (@CSVString, ',') A
        WHERE
            vn = 1
)
SELECT * FROM cteIdSplit S WHERE S.Id = @Id_To_Find;
```